# Resize image smaller so it can fit in the spans with the words

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get an image and some sentence to generate in the same row [image]

As  seen above it looks like that. I want the image to be right next to the information for the image. SO it wouldnt take up so much space.

```
@foreach (var m in Model.Matches)
{ 
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px">
    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px">
    <img src="@m.Photo.PhotoURL" class="img-responsive" @*style="max-height:175px;max-width:100px;"*@/>
    </div>
    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px">
     <h5>@m.Username</h5>
     <h5>@m.Age year old @m.Gender.WhatGender | Seeking</h5>
     <h5>@m.City, @m.State.Name,@m.State.Country.Name</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
     <hr />
}
```

The above code is generating the image with the information.  Im not sure what to include to make it have the image small enough on the left side and the informaiton to fit to the right of it.  Im using bootstrap also.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this (You didn't mentioned about responsiveness)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="span2 info" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px">
    <img src="" /> 
    <div class=" span2 info_text">
       <h5>Username</h5>
       <h5>Age year old Seeking</h5>
       <h5>City, State.Country Name</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (add these css code to your own css file)

```
.info img{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
}

.info_text{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WKYXT/3/)

**Note :** Also, make sure that, if you are using `responsive` template then you should adjust the image size according to device using [multiple media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) or [bootstrap way](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images).